# ubuntu-touch: quickest way to open a bookmark

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, scopes, m10

I recently bough a BQ M10 tablet. A lot of web site are not in the the ubuntu store (yet), or their apps are pretty buggy. So I have to deal with bookmarks all the time.

Opening a bookmark is pretty slow:

- swipe from the left
- start the browser
- click on the little '+'to get a new tab
- click on the bookmark
- close the useless 'ubuntu start page' tab

Do you have a quickest way ?

I think it would be useful to have a bookmark scope so I could access them efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bookmarks scope already, it's called Browser Bookmarks. You just have to install OpenStore to install said scope: http://notyetthere.org/openstore-tweakgeek-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

You may give the app called ["My Web Apps"](https://uappexplorer.com/app/mywebsites.mattirn) by Matti Rinta-Nikkola a try. This app gives you an option to store 20 different bookmarks and allows to access them easily. The same developer has similar apps for other specialised topics: [My News Apps](https://uappexplorer.com/app/mynewsapps.mattirn), [Google Apps](https://uappexplorer.com/app/googleapps.mattirn), [Wikimedia](https://uappexplorer.com/app/wikifoundation.mattirn), [Ubuntu Resources](https://uappexplorer.com/app/ubuntu.mattirn).

Answer (score 0):

There is a LastPass App on the Ubuntu Store. It is made to store passwords, but also organizes and launches the web addresses to the sites associated with the passwords. Seems to work reasonably well on M10 and seems to work for sites where you do not provide a password.